# How to loop outer glow layer style in After Effects?

Tags: after-effects, after-effects-expressions, after-effects-scripting

I have a layer in After Effects to which I have applied an outer glow as a layer style. Ideally I would like the glow to turn off and on, in a loop, starting at a point in time and then stopping. Is this possible—perhaps with a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest animate the 'Opacity' property of the *outer glow*:

[image]
*Click to enlarge*

1. Create a keyframe by clicking on the *stopwatch of outer glow* 'opacity' and set its value to `0%`
2. Create a second keyframe and set its value to `100%`
3. <kbd>Alt</kbd>*-Click* the stopwatch to create an expression and insert `loopOut(type = "pingpong")` to get an endless loop of *both* values

[image]
*Composition length: 49 Frames, 

2 Keyframes: frame `0` > opacity `0%`, frame `25` > opacity `100%`*

**Note:** In order to create a less generic animation, you can also create 3 or more keyframes by using `loopOut(type="cycle")` expression instead.

---

To start the animation at a predefined time as well as stop the animation as you like, you can either *duplicate the layer twice* and *remove the layer styles of both duplicates* in order to concatenate all 3 layers by hand or write a *simple condition* like this:

```js
// get the current frame of the composition
currentFrame = timeToFrames(time, 1 / thisComp.frameDuration, false);

// check if the current frame is in the predetermined range
if (currentFrame >= 20 && currentFrame <= 60) {
  // loop all keyframes
  loopOut(type = "cycle");
}
else{
  // if the current frame is not in predetermined range set glow opacity to 0
  thisLayer.layerStyle.outerGlow.opacity = 0;
}
```

[image]

*Composition length: 80 Frames, 

Loop animation range: Frame 20 - 60, 

3 Keyframes: frame `0` > opacity `0%` , frame `10` > opacity `100%`, frame `20`> opacity `0%`*

Official [expression language reference](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/expression-language-reference.html)

Comment: `timeToFrames(time, 1 / thisComp.frameDuration, false)` is the same as `time / thisComp.frameDuration` is it not? Simpler, and one fewer function call.

Comment: Yeah, good idea @stib. Feel free to edit my answer.